# Kotlin: Idiomatic way to call (Int, Int) -> Int with a Pair<Int, Int>?

Tags: java, functional-programming, kotlin

```
fun sum(a: Int, b: Int) = a + b
val x = 1.to(2)
```

I'm looking for:

1. `sum.tupled(x)`, or
2. `sum(*x)`

Of course, none of the above compiles with Kotlin 1.1.3-2. So am I stuck with `sum(x.first, x.second)`?

**Edit**:

Generalizing on the useful answers, I think this is the closest thing for now:

```
fun <P1, P2, R> Function2<P1,P2,R>.tupled(x: Pair<P1, P2>): R = invoke(x.first, x.second)
```

Answer (score 1):

After know about your needs, I think you needn't any overload funtions/extension functions at all, just using [KCallable#call](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-callable/call.html) instead, for example:

```
val x  = arrayOf(1, 2)

//                v--- top-level  functions 
val result:Int = ::sum.call(*x) 
//                  v--- member-level  functions 
val result:Int = this::sum.call(*x)
```

---

You also can overload the function `sum` in Kotlin just like as Java, for example:

```
sum(1 to 2)
sum(*intArrayOf(1, 2))

fun sum(tuple: Pair<Int, Int>) = sum(tuple.first, tuple.second)

fun sum(vararg pair: Int) = sum(pair[0], pair[1])
```

---

For, the `sum.tupled(x)` you can write an extension function, for example:

```
val sum: (Int, Int) -> Int = ::sum // top-level function
//OR
val sum:(Int, Int)->Int = this::sum // member scope function


// the final form is what you want 
//                       v
val result:Int = sum.tupled(1 to 2)

fun <T1,T2,R> Function2<T1,T2,R>.tupled(x:Pair<T1,T2>):R = invoke(x.first,x.second)
```

Comment: You've a typo in that `intArray` should be `IntArray`. But the more important part is that `sum(*IntArray(1, 2))` doesn't compile. The 2nd `Int` is conflicting with the `init` function of the constructor `IntArray(size: Int, init: (Int) -> Int)`

Comment: @Abhijit Sarkar yeah, I have no editor just two hands. Thanks, :)

Comment: Can you help me understand the `tupled` extension fn (I'm new to Kotlin)? `invoke` is defined in the `Function2`, right? So you're adding the same number to itself? That'd not be the `sum` in my question.

Comment: @Abhijit Sarkar hi, it is an Kotin builtin types just an alias of `(T,T)->R`.

Comment: @Abhijit Sarkar yeah, `invoke` is a member operator function of the `Function`s. it is, but you must using function reference to get the `sum`

Comment: Actually, `fun <P1, P2, R> Function2<P1,P2,R>.tupled(x: Pair<P1, P2>): R = invoke(x.first, x.second)` is what my definition of `sum` would be; yours is a `double`

Comment: @Abhijit Sarkar Hi, you have the original `sum(1,2)`, right? which takes 2 `Int`s, right? Please run my edited answer, sir.

Comment: I did and it gave me 4. `sum.tupled(1 to 2)` should be 3.

Comment: @Abhijit Sarkar Hi, I have seen your edited question, if you want to pass a `Pair` to the `sum` funtion, you can overload the original `sum` only. Since you use an extension function way you must get the function reference first.

Comment: @Abhijit Sarkar how about it now? I have edited my answer to meet your needs, I'm not convinient I'm on mobile. This is just my idea to using **curly** feature in Kotlin high-order functions.

Comment: @Abhijit Sarkar  Hi,to make my edited answer to run, you should add the `kotlin-reflect` into your project.

Answer (score 1):

You can also if you'd like to use Kotlin's sugary syntax write the following:

```
val sum : (Pair<Int,Int>) -> Int = { (a,b) -> a + b }
```

Comment: Now, `sum` can't be invoked with 2 `Int` :(

Comment: I didn't mean to replace the older sum, you can keep them both , they are not confilcting

Comment: Then your answer is similar to @holi-java. I'm sure I can have 2 different versions of the same method, but it'd be nice if the language could do that for me.

Comment: Keep in mind , destructuring declaration is not a change in the parameter type. You can't simply (as of now) use `(Int,Int) -> Int` as `(Pair<Int,Int>) -> Int`. Each one is different in how it works internally.

Comment: Internally , the system is calling `Pair.component1()` and `Pair.component2()` to fill the variables which to you look like parameters, but in fact they aren't.

Comment: Need a `lift` :)

Answer (score 0):

An extension function would also be a very convenient way:

```
fun Pair<Int, Int>.sum() = this.first + this.second
val x = 1.to(2)
x.sum()
```

Comment: Well, what if I also have `multiply`, and `subtract`? Creating an extension function for each one is a lotta work.

Comment: Yes, but you only have to to the work once and than you can use it everywhere by just importing the extension function.